# Getting inherited public static field with Reflection in Portable Class Libraries

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, portable-class-library

Within a Portable Class Library, I have 2 classes:

The parent

```
public class Parent
{
    public string inherited;
    public static string inheritedStatic;
}
```

And the child the derives from it

```
public class Child : Parent
{
    public static string mine;
}
```

The problem is that I cannot get the inherited static field named "inheritedState", I just get the non-static ("inherited").

This is the code that I'm running:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var childFields = typeof(Child).GetTypeInfo().GetRuntimeFields();

        foreach (var fieldInfo in childFields)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(fieldInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

What should I do to get the inherited static field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
public static FieldInfo[] DeclaredFields(TypeInfo type)
{
    var fields = new List<FieldInfo>();

    while (type != null)
    {
        fields.AddRange(type.DeclaredFields);

        Type type2 = type.BaseType;
        type = type2 != null ? type2.GetTypeInfo() : null;
    }

    return fields.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but that method call isn't available in portable class libraries. It doesn't accept the BindingFlags :(

Comment: @SuperJMN [here in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ztex2dc(v=vs.110).aspx) it is written *Supported in: Portable Class Library*... but if you say so...

Comment: @SuperJMN Changed the code... Now I cycle over the chain of base types and use `DeclaredFields`

Comment: Thank you #xanatos. By the way, I've double checks the method and I can affirm that the overload the takes a second argument (BindingFlags) isn't available in PCLs.

Answer (score 0):

For PCL library, and tested for my:

```
public static IEnumerable<FieldInfo> DeclaredFields(Type type)
    {
        var fields = new List<FieldInfo>();

        while (type != null)
        {
            fields.AddRange(type.GetRuntimeFields());
            type = type.GetTypeInfo().BaseType;
        }

        return fields;
    }
```